# IPC Error on GPG Agent with Git on Windows

Tags: windows, git, git-bash, gnupg, gpg-agent

I would like to use GPG without Gpg4win installed on Windows because [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/) includes the binary for GPG we well, so I would like to use it instead of installing an extra application.

However, when I setup the GPG (e.g adding Path etc), I have encountered the following error:

```
C:\Users\me> gpgconf --launch gpg-agent
gpgconf: error running '/usr/bin/gpg-connect-agent': exit status 1
gpgconf: error running '/usr/bin/gpg-connect-agent NOP': General error
```

And with `gpg-connect-agent`:

```
C:\Users\me> gpg-connect-agent /bye
gpg-connect-agent: no running gpg-agent - starting '/usr/bin/gpg-agent'
gpg-connect-agent: waiting for the agent to come up ... (5s)
gpg-connect-agent: waiting for the agent to come up ... (4s)
gpg-connect-agent: waiting for the agent to come up ... (3s)
gpg-connect-agent: waiting for the agent to come up ... (2s)
gpg-connect-agent: waiting for the agent to come up ... (1s)
gpg-connect-agent: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed
gpg-connect-agent: error sending standard options: No agent running
```

I need the agent to be running in order to sign the git commits, so I am not sure what is happening.

Before this error happens, I was using Gpg4win, which has no errors at all (to make sure it is not a versioning issue, I have removed everything in `%userprofile%/.gnupg`)

System Info:

- `Windows 10 21H1 19043.1110`
- `git version 2.29.2.windows.1`
- ```
  C:\Users\me> gpg --version
    gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.23-unknown
    libgcrypt 1.8.7
    Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
    This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
    There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

    Home: C:/Users/me/.gnupg
    Supported algorithms:
    Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
    Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
            CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
    Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
    Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
  ```
- `where gpg`: `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\gpg.exe`
- `where git`: `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure it out.

This is because the gpg in git for windows uses `MINGW64` for the environment. And because I manually set the `GNUPGHOME` environment variable to a Windows path: `C:/users/me/.gnupg`, it will not work.

(I never use the included `MINGW64` git bash, I only use cmd and add those exe, like git, gpg into `PATH`)

So, **if you have manually set the `GNUPGHOME` env variable, you need to change to a `MINGW64` path.**

So in my case, `C:/users/me/.gnupg` -> `/c/users/me/.gnupg`

I am not sure about `--homedir` though.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem on a fresh install of gnupg2 on a new MacOS (Monterey). It seems the installation doesn't create the `.gnupg` folder.

In my case this was solved by running:

`gpg -K`

which resulted in the creation of the **missing** folder

```
gpg: directory '/Users/xxx/.gnupg' created 
gpg: keybox '/Users/xxx/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
gpg: /Users/xxx/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
```

and all was well.

Comment: Alas same symptoms, but ~/.gnupg is already present and gpg -K returns "gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed".